# gradle exception with Android Room on parameterless doa definitions

Tags: java, android, android-room

I'm converting some Android db code form an annotation processor I wrote myself to Room.  I'm getting a really vague error.  After quite a bit time, through divide and conquer, I narrowed it down to two methods that run canned queries (i.e. it doesn't take any parameters).  Such as the following:

```
@Query("update blah set mDownloadStatus=3, mTaskId=0 where mDownloadStatus=2 or mDownloadStatus >= 4")
    void resetDownloads();
```

After running `./gradle --stacktrace assembleDebug`, I got the stacktrace below (there was more above it, but this is the meat of it).

> Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: List is empty.
>           at kotlin.collections.CollectionsKt___CollectionsKt.first(_Collections.kt:178)
>           at android.arch.persistence.room.writer.DaoWriter.createPreparedDeleteOrUpdateQueries(DaoWriter.kt:124)
>           at android.arch.persistence.room.writer.DaoWriter.createTypeSpecBuilder(DaoWriter.kt:86)
>           at android.arch.persistence.room.writer.ClassWriter.write(ClassWriter.kt:40)
>           at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomProcessor$DatabaseProcessingStep.process(RoomProcessor.kt:60)
>           at com.google.auto.common.BasicAnnotationProcessor.process(BasicAnnotationProcessor.java:318)
>           at com.google.auto.common.BasicAnnotationProcessor.process(BasicAnnotationProcessor.java:171)
>           at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:794)
>           at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:705)
>           at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1800(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:91)
>           at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1035)
>           at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1176)
>           at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1170)
>           at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:856)
>           at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)
>           ... 126 more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [a known bug in `1.0.0-alpha4`](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63608092). Drop back to `1.0.0-alpha3` until this gets fixed.